# jquery ajax response strips html <td> tags

Tags: html, ajax, tags, response, strip

I have a javascript / jquery function which is supposed to replace a row in a table with an "Edit Mode" version of the same row. it fires on the onclick event of a button on the row and a simplified verion of the code would be:

```
function EditRow(itemID) {
   editable_row = getUrl('row.php?action=' + 'edit' + '&itemID=' + itemID );
   $('[row_itemID=' + itemID + ']').html(editable_row);
}
```

(...row_itemID is an attribute of the TR tag for the row... as in [tr row_itemID="27"])

```
function getUrl(addr) {
   var r = $.ajax({ type: 'GET', url: addr, async: false, dataType: "text" }).responseText; return r;
}
```

(i have alse tried setting "dataType:" to 'html' or leaving it out altogether)

row.php should return the "Edit Mode" version of the contents of the row but for some reason the TD tags appear to get stripped in the process, maybe the $.ajax() function consideres a response containing TD 's without TR 's invalid.

A view-source of `row.php?action=edit&itemID=27` displays the TD 's and so does `alert(editable_row);`, but `alert($('[row_itemID=27]').html());` doesn't.

A simplified version of row.php code:

```
<?php 
if ($_GET['action'] == 'edit') {
   $item = ItemDataAccess::Read($_GET['itemID']);
?>
   <td><input type="text" name="itemID" value="<?php echo $item->itemID ?>" /></td>
   <td><input type="text" name="name" value="<?php echo $item->name ?>" /></td>
   <td><input type="text" name="description" value="<?php echo $item->description ?>" /></td>
<?php
}
?>
```

Does anyone now how to get it to insert an unadulterated html response into the TR tag?

Comment: `alert($('[row_itemID=27]').html());` isn't going to show anything until the HTML fragment is inserted into the document. That's because `$('[row_itemID=27]')` searches the document - it doesn't magically know to search the HTML fragment.

Comment: Ah Ok, thanks. I think that's my point though, that when inserted in the document the TD tags go missing

Answer (score -1):

You really wrote a wrapper around `$.ajax()`? Did you miss [`$.get()`](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.get) and [`.load()`](http://api.jquery.com/load)? And, *shudder* you're using `async: false` instead of a callback, why?

```
function EditRow(itemID) {
   $('[row_itemID=' + itemID + ']').load('row.php?action=' + 'edit' + '&itemID=' + itemID);
}
```

That's it.

Comment: someone else wrote the wrapper ;D and suggested I used it.

Comment: Nevertheless I have tried both get() and load() and both seem to still strip the TR's. ¿Any further ideas?

Comment: Hold on just a minute. What's missing - the **`<td>`s** or the **`<tr>`s**? I don't see anything in the PHP that outputs `<tr>`s, only `<td>`s.

Comment: that's correct... the calling page already has the TR where the TD's from the load are to be inserted into. the TD's get lost during the insert into the TR

Comment: What is `$('[row_itemID=' + itemID + ']').length`? If it's zero, no such element exists on the page at all, so you'll need to create one first.

Comment: Length is 1 in the production code. I have stripped down to the bare row.php and now the TD's get inserted. It must be a load of additional javascript I have in the production version that is causing the trouble. Many thanks for the help anyhow.